# Is the following set closed? $S={x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^t\in \mathbb{R}^n :x_1\geq 0}$

Tags: real-analysis

$$S=\{x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^t\in \mathbb{R}^n :x_1\geq 0\}$$

The definition I have for a closed set is as follows:

A set $E\subseteq \mathbb{R^n}$ is closed if and only if the set $E^c =\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n|x\not\in E\}$ is open.

And a subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if $\forall x \in U, \exists r>0: B_{r}(x)\subseteq U,\quad B_{r}(x)=\{y\in\mathbb{R}^n: ||x-y||<r\}$

Any answer or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the exponent of t mean?

Comment: @WilliamElliot transpose?

Comment: @Seh-kai.  How is it transposed?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Transposed into a column vector

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is closed. Any point $x$ in the complement of this set has a positive distance from this set. So any point which is within (say) half of that distance from $x$ must also lie in the complement of this set. In other words, we have constructed an open ball around an arbitrary point of the complement which is also in the complement as required.